# Get list of top ordered products

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

im tring to get the top products that are ordered and the quantity, but i notice that is giving me the sold products and not the ordered products that should be more, what is wrong with this code? Why is not showing the right results?

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '8000M');

require '../app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
function getBestsellingProducts()
{     
    // number of products to display
    $productCount = 400; 

    // store ID
    $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

    // get today and last 30 days time
    $today = time();
    $last = $today - (60*60*24*30);

    $from = date("Y-m-d", $last);
    $to = date("Y-m-d", $today);

    // get most view ed products for current category
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')        
                    ->addOrderedQty($from, $to)
                    //->setStoreId($storeId)
                    //->addStoreFilter($storeId)                    
                    ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
                    ->setPageSize($productCount); 

    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')
            ->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')
            ->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);

    return $products; 
}


$products = getBestsellingProducts();

foreach ($products as $key => $value) {

    $pro = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($value->getId());
    echo $pro->getName() ." - ". $pro->getSku() . " - " . $value->ordered_qty . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to get  top ordered products:

Step 1: Create a file `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Bestseller.php` and the following lines of code in it

```
lass Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Bestseller extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            ->addOrderedQty()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
            ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc'); // most best sellers on top
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);

        $products->setPageSize(3)->setCurPage(1);
        $this->setProductCollection($products);
    }
}
```

Step 2: Create a file `app/design/frontend/default/YourTheme/template/catalog/product/bestseller.phtml` file and add the following lines of code in it

```
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>
<div class="page-title">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Best Seller Products') ?></h2>
</div>
<?php $_collectionSize = count($_products->getItems()) ?>
<table class="products-grid" id="products-grid-table">
<?php $i=1; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
    <?php if ($i%1!==0): ?>
    <tr>
    <?php endif ?>
        <td id="td_<?php echo $i;?>" <?php if($i%3==0 or $i==$_collectionSize){echo 'class="last"';} ?> >
        <?php contentBlock('top') ?>
        <div id="cont_<?php echo $i;?>">
            <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a></h3>
            <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(122, 109); ?>" width="122" height="109" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" />
            </a>
            <div class="a-center">                        
                <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <button class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></span></button>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <p class="availability"><span class="out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <ul class="add-to-links">
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                        <li class="last"><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </ul>
                <?php if($_product->getevent_date()) {echo $_product->getevent_date();} ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <?php if ($i%3==0 or $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
   </tr>
    <?php endif ?>
  <?php $i++; endforeach; $kol = $_collectionSize; ?>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Step 3: This above files will create a list of best selling products which can be shown anywhere on your Magento store. All you have to do is place the following line of code block in your template to show the best selling products.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_bestseller" template="catalog/product/bestseller.phtml"}}
```

Now we are able to show best selling products anywhere in our Magento store.